# Update values in MainActivity every time when opened

Tags: android, eclipse, android-activity, oncreate

How can I call onCreate of the MainActivity every time I'm opening it?

I want to do this:
I open my app and this is my MainActivity, then I open ActivityB and save some data. When I close my ActivityB I'm coming back to MainActivity, but my data in MainActivity is not updated because onCreate is not being called.

Is it correct to solve it like this (this is working, but I know it's not a good way):

Button for going to ActivityB:

```
 public void ActivityB(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

Button for returning to MainActivity:

```
public void Back(View view){
    finish();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do in the `OnCreate` method?

Comment: Do it in onResume() instead.

Comment: @ Leandros - I'm reading data from database created in ActivityB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look into this:
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/pausing.html

Basically, every activity has more events other than "onCreate", like "onResume", which in this case should be called when MainActivity is back on the foreground, and you should put your code there.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake and just now corrected it and it's now working! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use `startActivityForResult`

```
public void ActivityB(View view){
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

}

Then on `onActivityResult`

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

    String sp = intent.getStringExtra("sp");
}
```

in Activity B

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.putExtra("sp", value); // the change value of sp
    setResult(RESULT_OK);
}
```

Comment: What kind of data you need to update and what do you do in onActivityResult

Comment: I need to update String by reading from database table.
I'm doing this:
SQLiteDbHelper db = new SQLiteDbHelper(this);
String sp = SQLiteDbHelper.getSP();

Comment: create a function that update String, call it in onCreate and call it in onActivityResult.

Comment: Can you post the onCreate for MainActivity and onActivityResult and the function you just created.

Comment: It's the same: SQLiteDbHelper db = new SQLiteDbHelper(this); String sp = SQLiteDbHelper.getSP();
onActivityResult is: super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent); and then my function

Comment: no, it's unchanged. it changes only in onCreate. your way or onResume() are not working.

Comment: Yes, it is update and working. When opening app, it's updated, but only in that case.

Comment: There is some issue that your database did not update right away. You should post that as a separate question concerning the database update. For just a string I updated my answer.

Comment: Database is updated immediately, checked with DDMS. Your solution is still not working.

Comment: Is there any flag that you declare your activities in the manifest file?

Comment: Sorry, I was making a mistake. The onResume() works perfectly, so I wasn't trying this any more.

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume you have an Textview in main Activity A and you are setting text using

```
Textview myTextview =(Textview)findViewbyId(R.id.textview1);
myTextView.setText("Android");
```

You are navigating from Activity A to Activity B. When activity B is finished onResume() method of Activity A is invoked. So update the textview as follows in onResume()

```
onResume(){
myTextview.setText("Jelly Bean")};
```

So whatever view you want to update when you come back to your screen do it on onResume() method of that acitivity. Hope it is clear